# how to convert service json data into array using angular js 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting this JSON data i want it to convert it to array and that array should come in the drop down list.

Here's my JSON data:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"inspiron"},{"id":"2","name":"lenovo"}]
```

I need to convert it to a drop down list like this:

[image]

Comment: please help me i am new to ionic

Comment: What have you done so far? Where in particular are you getting stuck?

Comment: Are you using Angular 2+, or Angular JS?

Comment: i am using Angular 2 and with this form i am trying to post the data to MySQL database and i am getting service JASON data and i want to convert that string to array format and that should come in the drop down list .... i don't know how to convert JSON data to array format so please help me to do that... thank you

Answer (score 0):

You really need to post more information. Preferably the code you have. Either you don't have any, in which  case you're just asking for people to do work for you, or you do and its something that will give context to your question and make it a lot easier to answer.

Your JSON is already in an array format. But you need it as a JavaScript object?

Then you need:

```
JSON.parse(responseText);
```

However, if you're using the built in Angular http stuff, your probably just need to call`response.json()` and it's already parsed. I've no idea because you've not posted what code you actually have.

Might be worth going back to the basics of JavaScript and typescript rather than jumping in with Angular.